# How to transform Serial Data from digital inclinometer to readable format in Python?

Tags: python

I bought a device (inclinometer) that produces data which I want to attach to my post in a readable format. How can I do this using python?

I have the following script:

```
import binascii
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
s = ser.read()
hex_string = binascii.hexlify(s).decode('utf-8')
print(hex_string)
```

I have added an example of how the inclinometer is sending data over COM port.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a line of real (hex)output from your device either by comment or by updating your question? Can you add a drawing or picture how the desired data should look like when you have it attached to your post? Perhaps also tell us more about the model of inclinometer and where you are posting it. Both are relevant if the output should be uploaded automatically onto your site you post.

Comment: That documentation is seriously bad. They give you 14 bytes of data but only document 9 bytes of it. I presume the first 4 bytes are some sort of preamble with `84` being an echo of the command, and the `FB` at the end is probably a checksum.

Answer (score 0):

As not all information is given to tailor the best answer some assumptions are made to narrow down the posibile answers.

In the example the assumption is taken that the datastream giving by the inclination-meter includes more than just x-axis and y-axis coordination. Therefor the while-loop is introduced. There is also a data-request pause from inclination-meter build in to prevent data-flooding in your destination device where you run this python script (raspberry-pi?).

Perhaps this script is used in multiprocessing mode? Then you might want to include a step where you compare current x,y coordinates against defined reference values (not included but should at the end of the while-loop).

```
import binascii
import serial
import time

set_sloop   = 0    # control flag for result
loop_checks = 0    # control flag to prevent data-flooding.

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)

while set_sloop == 0:                          # get hex-data from device every 2 seconds (see pause interval)

    s = ser.read()
    hex_string = binascii.hexlify(s).decode('utf-8')

    print(hex_string)

    if str(hex_string[0:9]) == '680D008400':   # used (x,y) string identifier based on example 0x84.
        xh = hex_string[10:13]
        yh = hex_string[16:19]
        x  = '%s.%s' % xh[0:1], xh[2:3]
        y  = '%s.%s' % yh[0:1], yh[2:3]
        xt = 'x = %s deg' % x
        yt = 'y = %s deg' % y

        print (xt, yt)
        set_sloop = 1

    loop_checks += 1

    if loop_checks == 10:
        time.sleep(2)    # pause interval: wait 2 seconds before requesting new data.
        loop_checks = 0


print ('got inclination: (%s , %s) deg' % x, y)


 # ... remaining code to "auto-post inclination" goes here ...
```

> Note: take into account that the searchstring '680D008400' is not completely according the description given in the example. There is missing a set of digits. Typo in company text?